# Input in array without adding increment operator ++

Tags: c++, arrays

I would like some confirmation (or refutation) about something.

I was just busy with a simple exercise placing statements inside loop conditionals. Basically I created an array of 5 elements and then have the user input 5 values that will be stored in the array. Pretty basic stuff. But then I started wondering: What if I replaced the `a[i++]` in my code with simply `a[i]`? So I did, and the resultant output was that I (i.e. the user) just kept inputting values seemingly infinitely, i.e. not stopping at only 5 inputs.

Now then I made the assumption that what might be happening is that now the program simply replaces every new input value with the previous one and storing it in element 0 of the array, over and over, hence it not stopping at 5.

Is this assumption of mine is correct? If not, then please shed some light on what exactly is happening here. This might be a very nonsensical thing to be concerned about, but I'd really like to know either way.

```
//array test
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int a[5] = { 0 };
  int i = 0;

  while(std::cin >> a[i++] && i < 5);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cout` the contents of the array inside the `while` loop to see what's happening.

Comment: Yes, I did do that also and the program just spit out a whole lot of random numbers. Probably about 100 of them or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the i++ and replace it with only i, you are replacing a[0] indefinitely.

a[i++] evaluaves to a[i], and AFTER that increases i by one. So when i reaches 5, the second part of your condition (i<5) is not true and exits from the while loop.

Comment: This is probably the closest to what answer I was looking for. So you basically are saying, yes, my assumption was indeed correct. The program just replaces the input value in element 0 of the array over and over. Thanks, mate :)

Answer (score 2):

So, you are basicly asking what's the difference between `i` and `i++`?  It's rather basic C/C++ (note the ++ here!).  I suggest you google for "C++ postincrement operator" :)

Comment: Also, the code sample, although syntactically correct, is not very readable and, more importantly, over-reliant on literals.  It could be rewritten in a much more readable and safe manner, which can be left as an exercise to the curious reader :)

Comment: Well, I know the difference between i and i++. What I basically wanted to know is what exactly the program was doing when I made that little change.  More out of curiosity than anything else. That's why I pointed out that it may be nonsensical. All I wanted was just some confirmation on my assumption, since I did not want to be believe the incorrect things regarding how inputs were stored into arrays, if you get what I mean.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean with it is not "very readable". It seems quite readable to me. Could you elaborate please? Also how is this not safe?

Comment: @AshleyPieterse since this loop structure doesnt follow common idioms it takes a while for the reader to check that there isn't an off-by-one error. Many people try to avoid empty loop bodies for readability reasons too. I'd personally consider writing this loop as `for (i = 0; i < 5 && std::cin; ++i)` `std::cin >> a[i];`  .  You could keep the `cin >> a[i]` in the condition though, but it makes a big difference to readability to hoist out the `++` into a traditional `for` loop pattern.

Comment: Using trailing `;` to indicate an empty loop body can make it look like a typo when in fact it was intentional; I use trailing `{ }` instead.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Alright, I think I know what you mean. I will use the suggested methods instead from now on. And will also go read up on the "off-by-one error" you mentioned, as this is something new to me. Thanks. :)

Comment: ps. I also see I got 3 downvotes. I didn't realize my question was that bad haha  . Next time I will stop wondering what the program is doing behind the scenes and just get on with the coding :|  :P

Comment: @AshleyPieterse, don't stop wondering about what the code actually does - it's the only thing that can make you a good developer! :)  Just try to do your own homework before posting to SO.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I used your method and also fiddled around a bit with the code to see what happens. I removed the && std::cin part you added in the for loop and it didn't seem to make any difference to the way the program ran. Is it okay to leave it out, or is there some reason why the && std::cin part has to be included in the loop that might not be immediately apparent?

Comment: @AshleyPieterse well, your original code did it. The purpose is to abort the loop if the input fails (i.e end of file, or something typed that is not a number) .  If you take it out then you won't know whether they typed `1 2 3 0 0` or `1 2 3 snargl`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're correct.

Just test it, remove the `++` and run.

Comment: Yes I did test and run it already and got infinite amount of inputs, as I stated in my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want "having a loop with no code inside", do not use `std::cin >> a[i++]` expression as condition (I think it will always `true`). Better use comma operation, e.g.:

```
   while(std::cin >> a[i++], i < 5);
```

Moreover, in the condition expression like `(std::cin >> a[i++]) && (i < 5)` left part (i.e. `(std::cin >> a[i++])`) can be skipped because optimization done by compiler (so `i++` will not be executed).